# Generating a unique random non-key value in Entity Framework/SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, random

I have a booking application where a customer will create a reservation. I do not want them to have to create an account and log in, so they will modify/view their reservation using a Confirmation code (like the airlines use) and the last 4 of their credit card (again, like airlines).  My reservation class already has a primary key, a GUID, however, I do not want to give that to the customer, I want something nicer to look at like a 6-8 digit alpha code.

I am using Entity Framework and C#/ASP.NET Core, and while I COULD generate the value in my code, check with the DB (MSSQL) that the value has not been used, and then persist if it is unique, I would rather have a single operation if I could.  Is the accepted way of doing something like this to have the database generate the value or is there a more EF way of doing it?

Comment: I would take the GUID and grab X number of characters from it add to it for example the last 4 digits of CC like you mentioned and save that as BookingRef or something.  All this would happen at the point where your booking is finalised.

Comment: There are many examples for generating user-enterable, mostly unique values, for C#. Commonly this problem is covered by One Time Passwords. (OTPs) In the end you will still need to check that these values are unique, so from an EF perspective that means having a unique constraint and index on these values then doing a fast `.Any()` query across the data to check for a duplicate with the insert exception as the extremely rare failsafe. If these are temporary in nature then it would be advisable to delete them from the row once no longer applicable to reduce recalculation as the table fills up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a two-factor (TOTP) code, but based on your GUID instead of a timestamp?

```cs
// userData should be populated with whatever immutable user data you want
// applicationSecret should be a constant
public string ComputeCode(byte[] userData, byte[] applicationSecret, int length)
{
    using var hashAlgorithm = new HMACSHA256(applicationSecret);
    var hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(userData);
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the EF-related aspects of your question, but I recently had to figure out a way to generate unique, user-friendly IDs for a personal project.

What I eventually settled on was the following:

1. Start with a 32-bit integer. (In my case it was an incrementing database ID.)
2. "Encrypt" the integer using [RC5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5) with a block size of 32 bits. This scrambles the key space. You'll probably have to write your own RC5 implementation, but it's a simple algorithm. (Mine was <100 lines of python.)
3. Encode the resulting 4 bytes in [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32). I recommend z-base-32 for the most user-friendly alphabet. You might have to write your own Base32 implementation, but again, it's quite simple.

This algorithm produces a reversible mapping similar to the following:

```
1 <-> "4zm5cna"
2 <-> "5ytgepe"
3 <-> "e94rs4e"
etc.
```